# Is it possible to create an iOS app that communicates wirelessly with an Arduino device?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, arduino, wifi

Like the title says, is it possible to create an iOS app that communicates wirelessly with an Arduino device, whether it's bluetooth or wifi, etc?

As an addon question, can bluetooth or wifi work through materials such as thick plastic?

Comment: Have a look at the LightBlue bean - this is an Arduino the BLE built in and a comprehensive iOS SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either user bluetooth or wifi direct for the wireless communication  . Apple provided rich apis for these framework.

For wifi direct there is framework called **Multipeer Connectivity** . You can find documentation : https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/index.html

For Bluetooth there is framework called **Core Bluetooth** , you can find the documentation :
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html

Comment: Multipeer connectivity won't really help here - it would be very hard to implement on Arduino.  You could use ordinary TCP/IP though.